# Editing shapefile while using definition query in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, editing, definition-query

Is it possible to edit shapes while using a "definition query" or "query builder" in QGIS?

I'm trying to do this in the same way I used to in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is **not** possible to edit a shapefile with a query. Following this ticket: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/2951, it is a matter of the underlaying OGR shapefile driver.

To solve the problem, store your data in a spatialite database, which can be queried and edited with no problems. That's what databases are designed for; a shapefile only comes with limited database-like functions.